# Moderate comments in Comment Box

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

Actually i'm implementing a Facebook Page Tab with the Comment Box plugin.

I'm using the HTML5 Code to display the plugin.

As written in the doc about comments moderation I have added the following :

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="{YOUR_APPLICATION_ID}"/>
```

when i use the debugger i get errors that must be fixed : Object at URL of type 'website' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'fb:admins' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.

when i remove the  `<meta property="fb:admins" content="{YOUR_FACEBOOK_USER_ID}"/>` no errors are displayed.

My problem is the following, i can't moderate comments (remove comments from other users, etc.).

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing any code of you: to gain moderation rights for social plugins embedded in a page, put the following OG-Tag in the head section of your page:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="[YOUR FB ID]" />
```

Put your facebook ID there. You can specify a commaseperated list of multiple IDs, too.

Comment: Hello Christian, i have edited my code ...
When I use the meta property fb:admins I can't get the moderation working

Comment: May you post the URL of the page with the problem so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I have made a test page at the following url : https://facebook.noviris.com/tests

Comment: what we have to do if we are using asp.net masterpage means it dosen't have head section it only have content . Where we have to put meta tags? please help.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following method:

Put this in you Document in the head section:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jayeshjain24ec" /> //username of moderater
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.something.com/" />
```

---

step 1) Go to this url : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

---

step 2) Enter your URL and click on debug.
In case if there is anything to be corrected,it will be mentioned here.

---

step 3)Correct all the warnings.Check the Scraped URL link at the bottom.Make sure it gets all the required Meta tags.

You will get a moderation option on your website once everything is ok.

### ALTERNATE SOLUTION:

Give yourself admin rights for the app(there is an option in settings).

go to this url: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=queue

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the website in you apps

Go [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)

Select the app for which you have added facebook comment box in the left

Go to >>> Edit App

Just before the end of the page, there "Select how your app integrates with Facebook"

In website : fill your website name

and

in App on Facebook >> fill the canvas url again as your website...

Then...

In the app domain above.. on the same

put your website name without using "http:/"

Click on "Save Change"

You are done

:)

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but in case anyone needed this:

> "You can specify either fb:app_id or fb:admins, but not both."

From facebook comments plugin [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/#moderation-setup-instructions)